# JSON optional field instead of required field

Tags: json, azure

I would like to make my vNet Id 2 parameter field optional for data instead of required since it's not always the case the data is required in both fields.

I'm very new to JSON and this template is a copy of this one from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/use-approved-vnet-vm-nics

I just want to vNet Id 2 to be optional for data instead of required.

```
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipconfigurations[*].subnet.id",
            "like": "[concat(parameters('vNetId'),'*')]"
          }
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipconfigurations[*].subnet.id",
            "like": "[concat(parameters('vNetId2'), '*')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "vNetId": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "vNet Id",
        "description": "Resource Id for the vNet"
      }
    },
    "vNetId2": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata":{
        "displayName": "vNet Id 2",
        "description": "Resource Id for the vNet"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft docs for parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#parameters), you can specify a `defaultValue` field within the parameter object that will be used when a value is not provided, effectively making it optional, i.e.

```
"vNetId2": {
  "type": "String",
  "defaultValue": "",
  "metadata": {
    "displayName": "vNet Id 2",
    "description": "Resource Id for the vNet"
  }
}
```

Note that according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869155/azure-resource-manager-how-to-specify-optional-parameters-in-linked-templates/55874087#55874087) on a similar question you must use an empty string rather than `null`.